# MVVM C# WPF - UI not updating when changing items in observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I've been looking at Stackoverflow posts regarding this issue for two days now and I cant seem to understand why my code isn't working

I can't seem to get the datagrid in my UI to update when I change an item within a `ObservableCollection`.

I know that the `ObservableCollection` does not trigger a `PropertyChanged` event if a item within it changes.

It seems like others have successfully done this by adding `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the Model, and calling `OnPropertyChanged` when the property is changed. I've implemented this and I've checked that the `PropertyChanged` event is going off.

The UI updates when adding new items to the collection.

I realize this might be a threading issue, but I don't really understand how to check this or fix it.

I'm fairly new to programming and trying to wrap my head around MVVM.

Any suggestions?

**Model:**

```
public class ModelObj : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }

    private DateTime timer;

    public DateTime Timer
    {
        get { return timer; }
        set
        {
            timer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ModelObj> ModelObjects { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ModelObj>();

    private IUdpDataService _udpDataService;

    public MainViewModel(IUdpDataService udpDataService)
    {
        _udpDataService = udpDataService;
    }

    public void StartUdpDataService()
    {
        _udpDataService.StartBroadCasting();
        _udpDataService.ReceivedDataEvent += ParseReceivedData;
    }

    private void ParseReceivedData(string receivedData)
    {
        // This object contains all the information in the received data packet. 
        UdpPacket udpPacket = new UdpPacket(receivedData);

        // This object only contains the object name, IpAddress and a time variable.
        ModelObj modelObj = new ModelObj
        {
            Name = udpPacket.Name,
            IpAddress = udpPacket.IpEthernet,
            Timer = DateTime.Now,
        };

        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            UpdateList(modelObj);
        });
    }

    private void UpdateList(ModelObj modelObj)
    {
        var testObj = ModelObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == modelObj.Name);
        if (testObj != null)
        {
            testObj = modelObj
        }
        else
        {
            ModelObjects.Add(modelObj);
            testObj = modelObj;
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainWindow(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        DataContext = _viewModel;
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel.StartUdpDataService();
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
            Settings.Default.Save();
            base.OnClosing(e);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
     <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelObjects}"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              Background="white"
              RowHeaderWidth ="0" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="auto" MinWidth="150"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP address" Binding="{Binding IpAddress}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Timer" Binding="{Binding Timer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: If you change the value in a cell, `..PropertyChanged` doesn't fire until the cell you are editing loses focus (click on another cell), you may want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanging` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `Timer` property of the existing object:

```
private void UpdateList(ModelObj modelObj)
{
    var testObj = ModelObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == modelObj.Name);
    if (testObj != null)
    {
        testObj.Timer = modelObj.Timer
    }
    else
    {
        ModelObjects.Add(modelObj);
    }
}
```

You are currently getting a reference to the existing object and then set the `testObj` variable that holds this reference to the reference to the new `ModelObj` object that is passed to the `UpdateList` method. This won't update the `Timer` property of the object that's in `the` ModelObjects collection.

Comment: He is not updating Timer only, as I understood he want to replace entire object (so new ipAddress and other fields will be there as well)

Comment: Only the Timer property raises the PropertyChanged event. Besides, he is mapping modelObj to testObj based on the name so this can't likely change.

Comment: Thanks! Stupid mistake, but that oldObj = newObj would "move" the properties values and then triggering the propertychanged event.

Comment: @AndréNicolaysen This code is not same, it does not copy IpAddress as your initial code did. But the destination was wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
testObj = modelObj
```

Does not have effect. You just putting a value in to variable. Call

```
    if (testObj != null)
    {
        ModelObjects.Replace(testObj,modelObj)
    }
    else
    {
        ModelObjects.Add(modelObj);
    }
```

and if you replacing entire object there is no need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged at all